# How to navigate between procedure / function heading and main code

Tags: delphi, rad-studio

If I have my cursor on a `procedure` or `function` definition, is there a quick way to navigate to the beginning of the main code (`begin`) for the procedure or function, skipping over all the embedded `procedure` and `function` declarations (and preferably also navigate in the reverse direction)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Ctrl+Shift+DownArrow` or `Ctrl+Shift+UpArrow` will jump between declaration and implementation sections in the same unit.

You can find the keyboard key mapping documentation [here](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Sydney/en/Default_Keyboard_Shortcuts).

Comment: My interpretation of the OP is that the OP wants to jump between the `procedure/function` line *of the definition* and the `begin` of the definition (hence moving past local variables, constants, types, functions, and procedures).

Comment: @Andreas Yes, that's what I understood as well. I made a little test with D10.4.1 and it jumps to the first line of the actual procedure, skipping the embedded procedures.

Comment: Agreed. However, it jumps to/from the `procedure/function` of the *declaration*, not the `procedure/function` of the *definition*. Hence, I suspect the OP wants to make a smaller jump than is produced by Ctrl+Shift+Arrow. However, if you are the `procedure/function` of the definition, you can press this keyboard combination twice to go to the `begin`. (Going back to the `procedure/function` of the definition, however, is not possible.)